# Is this sentence grammatically correct or not?

Tags: grammar

Is this correct?

*Such cooperation can prepare students to be good team players **and understand** the value of other people’s perspectives.*

Or should it be "...players and **to** understand..."

Or would both versions be correct?

Thank you!

Comment: The second version is somewhat nonsensical.

Answer (score 1):

I believe both are ok, but I suggest inserting 'to' gives 'understanding' equal emphasis with being good team players.

Answer (score -1):

"...prepare students ... to understand" doesn't really work. *They prepared him to understand*  is grammatical but a strange idea.  You really need to add another verb: "... can prepare students to be good team players and help them to understand" or "... and help them to see".

```
  can
       prepare students to be ...

  and

  (can)

       help them to ...
```

You can repeat or omit the second "can". The choice is a matter of style.

Answer (score -1):

> Such cooperation can prepare students to be good team players and understand the value of other people’s perspectives.

This is a matter of parallelism and elision.

You can look at it this way:

> Such cooperation can prepare students **to** [be good team players] and [understand the value of other people’s perspectives].

If either one of either one of those phrases were missing and the *to* were removed, it would be ungrammatical:

> ✘ Such cooperation can prepare students understand the value of other people’s perspectives.

In the shorter sentence, the *to* is required:

> ✔ Such cooperation can prepare students **to** understand the value of other people’s perspectives.

But when we read the sentence with the conjunction and the *to* in front of both items, we mentally assign it to both of them:

> ✔ Such cooperation can prepare students **to** be good team players and ***[to]*** understand the value of other people’s perspectives.

As such, both versions are fine—either with the second *to* or without it. It's more natural to leave it out, but including it is by no means wrong—since it's implicitly there anyway.

Comment: I don't think they're fine but the objection is not on grammatical grounds.  "... *prepare* them ...  to understand" is semantically a poor choice.

Comment: I've asked several native speakers of AmE and they all said "prepare them to understand" sounds like something a non-native speaker would say. It's grammatical but a tad "off".